# Volume calculation analysis with Quick Terrain Modeler 8.0.2. (QTM)

Tags: lidar, volume

I have been unsuccessful in finding a tutorial, guide or example of the 'Volume Calculation' analysis tool in Quick Terrain Modeler. 
http://appliedimagery.com/

I was wondering if anyone else has any success stories they would wish to share and/or how (in)/accurate they have found it to be when comparing (for example) a building while empty versus a building while occupied. How accurate were the measurement(s) between an empty structure and one that is filled, and how long does the calculation generally take (obviously it depends on the size though)? Unfortunately, I'm currently having issues with my LiDAR datasets, so I have yet to test it out myself, nor do I currently have a 'bare' dataset in which to reference to one that is occupied/filled.

Is anyone aware of better (or free) software that also does volume calculation analysis?

I'm using Quick Terrain Modeler v8.0.2. (x64) Build 80777.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received the following response from Support@AppliedImagery.com (the makers of QTM)

> The volume calculation tool enables the user to perform very accurate
>   and fast calculations regarding the volume of objects or terrain in
>   the model.  It can also be used in conjunction with other models to
>   calculate the difference in volume between the same areas of two
>   different models (i.e., volume change analysis).   In order to use the
>   tool, the user must:   •First define a subset of the model for which
>   the volume calculation is needed.  This selection can be performed
>   with either the Select or Select Polygon tool.   •Once the area has
>   been defined, the user must decide what to compare the volume to in
>   the Model 2 field.  The choices are:
>
> 1. Compare to a reference plane.  This would be useful of excavation is required to a known level plane (e.g., a new roadbed).  The user
>      can select this as "Model 2" in the Volume Calculation window.  If the
>      user selects a reference plane, the height (altitude) of the plane
>      must be input into the "Reference" window.  In the example below, the
>      input Reference was simply the altitude of the surface of the water,
>      172 meters.
> 2. Compare to another model.  This model must be loaded into the Quick Terrain Modeler prior to performing the calculation.  It may be useful
>      to compare to other models for mining, forestry and geology
>      applications. •Once the comparison has been defined as above, the user
>      must then choose how to measure the comparison.  The choices are as
>      follows:
> 3. Signed Delta Volume:  Calculates the net change in volume in the defined area.  For example, if 100 cubic meters was removed in one
>      place and 100 cubic meters was added in another place, the signed
>      delta volume would be zero.
> 4. Unsigned Delta Volume:  Calculates the absolute values of the change in volume in the defined area.  For example, if 100 cubic
>      meters was removed in one place and 100 cubic meters was added in
>      another place, the signed delta volume would be 200 cubic meters.
> 5. Volume of 1 Above 2:  Simply the amount of volume of Model 1 above Model 2 (or Reference Plane).
> 6. Volume of 2 Above 1:  Simply the amount of volume of Model 2 above Model 1 (or Reference Plane).
>
> •The resulting volume calculation will be in the model's units.  For
>   example, if the model is built in feet, the result will be in cubic
>   feet.  If the model is built in meters, the result will be in cubic
>   meters.
>
> Example:  Volume Calculation of hill based on comparison to a flat
>   plane at an elevation of 172 meters.